# how to find no of duplicate values in arraylist

Tags: c#

I have a arraylist which has values some of them are repeated. I need the count of the repeated values. Is this possible in c#?

Comment: Do you want "classic" C# syntax or is using Linq OK? (i.e. are you using 3.5?)

Comment: Do you want a count of items that are repeated or a total number of repeats? Meaning, `foo` is in the list three times, is that 1 item that is repeated or is it 2 repeats?

Comment: I need in pure c #, its no of times foo is repeated

Comment: If foo is there 3 times then i would need it say 3.

Comment: @Prady, I think I got what you need

Comment: I am using 2.0 . can i use linq with it?

Comment: See this: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/09/05/linq-support-on-net-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If your object has equals method correctly overrided just call `Distinct()` from `System.Linq` namespace on it

It requires the ArrayList to be homogeneous and calling `Cast<YourType>()` before `Distinct()`.

Then subtract the length of arrayList from the Distinct sequence.

```
arraList.Count - arraList.Cast<YourType>().Distinct().Count()
```

it will throw exception if your items in arrayList is not of type `YourType`, and if you use `OfType<YourType>` it filters items to objects of type `YourType`.

but if you want the count of each repeated item, this is not your answer.

Comment: Distinct removed dups, not found ;)

Comment: It's better to use `OfType<T>` rather than `Cast<T>` because first will return only proper objects while your - will raise an error. Anyway, it's much better to use generic collections

Answer (score 3):

[here](http://www.thereforesystems.com/find-duplicates-using-linq/) is a great post how to do it with LINQ

```
var query =
    from c in arrayList
    group c by c into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select new { Item = g.Key,  ItemCount = g.Count()};

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Country {0} has {1} cities", item.Item , item.ItemCount );
}
```

Comment: he says he doesn't use linq but that's exactly what I was going to enter.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Dictionary<T,int> CountOccurences<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) {
  var occurences = new Dictionary<T,int>();
  foreach(T item in items) {
    if(occurences.ContainsKey(item)) {
      occurences[item]++;
    } else {
      occurences.Add(item, 1);
    }
  }
  return occurences;
}
```

Comment: +1 Simple and easy to understand.  Although I think you meant `occurences.Add`, not `occurences.Put`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why so many people insist using Linq for each and every problem. That's pretty unredable most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

```
myList.GroupBy(i => i).Count(g => g.Count() > 1)
```

and if you specifically need ArrayList

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(new[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 });
Console.WriteLine(arrayList.ToArray().GroupBy(i => i).Count(g => g.Count() > 1));
```

Based on comments by poster

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(new[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 });
Console.WriteLine(arrayList.ToArray().Count(i => i == 4));
```

Comment: -1: It doesn't show the correct number of duplicates and also the example shown is with list, not with ArrayList.

Comment: +1 wouldn't you need something like this: `.GroupBy(i => i).Count(g => g == "foo" && g.Count() > 1)` in addition?

Comment: @hunter depends on how you read the question. I'm still not sure I quite understand what he's looking for.

Comment: @hunter, I don't know that reference.

Comment: @Yuriy, try to add another "4" into the array. Your LINQ query will return again "2" while "the repeated values" are three.

Comment: @AS-CII I thought that was the intent. Hard to tell from the question, I'll update based on his comments in one second.

Comment: -1 removed. @Yuriy, put -1 on last Count() example. I think that, again, there is only one repeated value in your last snippet ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
int countDup = ArrayList1.Count - ArrayList1.OfType<object>().Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: So if one item is repeated 5 times, you would return 4 repeated items?

Comment: change the Length to Count dude :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = arrayList.Cast<object>()
  .GroupBy(o => o)
  .Select(g => new { Item = g, Count = g.Count() })
  .ToList();
```

each item of result list will have two properties:
Item - source item
Count - count in source list

Answer (score 0):

You could sort it, then it becomes very easy.

Edit: sorting becomes a moot point when done this way.

```
Arraylist myList = new ArrayList();

myList = someStuff;
Dictionary<object, int> counts = new Dictionary<object,int>();
foreach (object item in myList)
{
    if (!counts.ContainsKey(item))
    {
       counts.Add(item,1);
    }
    else
    {
       counts[item]++;
    }

}
```

Edit:

Some minor things might vary (not certain about some of my square braces, I'm a little rusty with c#) but the concept should withstand scrutiny.

Comment: I don't get why this has to be sorted.

Comment: Because if you don't sort it, you would have to scan the list for each object(foreach within a foreach), this makes it much faster.

Comment: suppose there is foo 3 times, fee 2 times, how do i get to see foo=3 and fee=2 . Pls forgive me if the question was very basic in nature

Comment: I was reading your code how I thought you should do it I guess.  Shouldn't you just increment counts[object] if it exists and make it 1 if it doesn't while looping through the list once?

Comment: @Prady: You could then loop through the dictionary and print off the values.  @Blankasaurus: You are quite right, the dictionary can essentially act as my temp object, that was stupid of me.  I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can acomplish this many ways.  The first that comes to me would be to group by the values within your array list, and only return the grouping counts that are over 1.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.Add("a");
al.Add("b");
al.Add("c");
al.Add("f");
al.Add("a");
al.Add("f");

int count = al.ToArray().GroupBy(q => q).Count(q=>q.Count()>1);
```

`count` will return the value of 2 as `a` and `f` are duplicated.