# How I can control a ArrayList for duplicate value?

Tags: c#, arraylist, duplicates

I have a arraylist with string(codes) and I want to control whether a string is duplicate in this arraylist. if the string is duplicate i want a other code to the arraylist.

my code:

```
private void btn_Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    try
    {
        list = DoDeserialize(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_status.Text = ex.Message; 
    }

    string code = GetCode(7);

    code = "2 - " + code;

    int test = list.IndexOf(code); 

    txt_Code.Text = code;
    lbl_status.Text = "Code wurde erstellt";


    list.Add(code);

    DoSerialize(list);
}
```

Comment: Could you use `List<string>`? A better choice. Just saying..

Comment: You can check if the content is already available using perhaps, `List#contains()` in Java , not sure of C# !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564095/how-to-find-no-of-duplicate-values-in-arraylist

Comment: `List<T>.Contains()` in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in place of your `list.add(code);`. This method checks whether the item is already in the array list.

```
if(!list.Contains(code))
{
    // The code does not already exist in the list, so add it
    list.add(code);
} else {
    // The code already exists, do something here.
}
```

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) for more information about the `List<T>.Contains()` method.

Comment: And there is probably an `else` here too right? The OP stated they wanted to add a different code if it's a duplicate -- or at least I **think** that's what they meant. :D

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Good point. I have added the else branch, and comments to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **LINQ** method `Distinct` to remove any duplicates after you have populated your list.